# How to conduct experiments comparision for academic paper in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning

I am writing my academic paper in deep learning. But I am not sure how to compare two methods/models appropriately. For example,

1. Should I set the same learning rate for both baseline and my own method?
2. Should I fix batch size for both baseline and my own methods?

Furthermore, I would be grateful if anyone could provide relevant slides/tutorial/blog.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; It depends

Most papers have highly tuned hyper-parameters. Therefore your new, say model architecture, will be at a big disadvantage if you keep learning-rate/batch size etc.. consistent.

This depends on what you are testing.

General guidence is to set some **Budget** that is consitent across the literature you are trying to outperform.

- This could be number of parameters
- Time to get to X performance
- Raw performance on number of observations

This will need to be tuned to your specific solution.

The most interesting papers I've looked at will vary both lr and batch-size, then unpack how the new approach behaves differenlty in each condition.
E.g. Use this new method if you have a lot of GPU RAM and can afford a larger batch size.